# Calculating the spatial variance of well density?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, point-in-polygon, zonal-statistics, kernel-density

I have wells as a point shapefile and have calculated the spatial density of these wells in 400+ basins (polygons) by dividing the number of wells in each basin (found by doing a spatial join) by the basin's area in acres.

However, I am stuck on trying to find a way to calculate the spatial variance of the well densities in each pbasin. The within-basin spatial variance is the variance of well density across each basin. In other words, how much does well density vary across each basin (polygon)? A basin with all wells placed exactly equi-distant from one another would have no spatial variance in well density, while a basin with 1,2,...,n clusters of wells that are all packed tightly together would have a high spatial variance. I am looking for an easy way to calculate this reliably.

I'm using ArcMap for Desktop 10.3.1

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I'm using ArcMap for Desktop 10.3.1

Comment: Repeat the same thing for each polygon what you did for entire area. If this is what you call spatial variance

Comment: Me thinks that spatial variance does not mean what you think it means. This is a very specific term in spatial statistics and has nothing to do with what you seem to be after. Can you please explain in more detail, exactly what you are after, even if conceptually and drop the jargon. It is also incorrect to derive a distributional measure of a spatial process from a kernel density estimate. This should be done directly from the observational data.

Comment: Let me know if this is clearer: The within-basin spatial variance is the variance of well density across each basin. In other words, how much does well density vary across each basin (polygon)? A basin with all wells placed exactly equi-distant from one another would have no spatial variance in well density, while a basin with 1,2,...,n clusters of wells that are all packed tightly together would have a high spatial variance. We are looking for an easy way to calculate this reliably.

Comment: It is a little bit clearer but you need to modify your answer if you want the question reopened. And, once again what you are describing is not spatial variance. You are describing two separate things: density and clustering. It sounds like you are after clustering, which can be measured by a point pattern statistic that compares your observed spatial pattern against a null. I normally do not recommend ArcGIS but, you can quantify if your point process is dispersed or clustered using the nearest neighbor index (ArcGIS Average Nearest Neighbor tool).